# How can I split points in a map

Tags: leaflet, zooming, r-leaflet

I use RStudio with leaflet package.

At a fine zoom level in a map, Is there a solution to split 2 points that are located at the same address?

Comment: You can use a plugin to do this [Leaflet.markercluster](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster)

Comment: it's not like this exactly. I have some points which are projected in the same place on the map. I used to use clusterOptions=markerClusterOptions but it's not exactly what I want. Finally, i find this : Etude$Lat <-jitter(Etude$Latitude, factor = 0.25)